# Problem with command line in windows

Tags: windows-vista, command-line

I copy the cmd.exe to a new location, then I run it to get the current directory location at that folder. But just recently, there is always this message:

```
Impossibile trovare il testo del messaggio per il numero di messaggio 0x2350 nel file di messaggio per Application.

Impossibile trovare il testo del messaggio per il numero di messaggio 0x2334 nel file di messaggio per Application.

C:\cygwin\home\Hoang>
```

Someone know how to solve it?

Comment: Message is "Can not find message text for message number 0x2334 in the message file for Application" in English (or at least it is according to Google)

Comment: Same issue. Works on my computer but shows the error on my boss's computer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open a command prompt at a specfic location, just hold down the Shift key when you right-click on a file or folder, and you should see the Open Command Window Here menu item.

Comment: Good point - I missed that!

Comment: moving cmd.exe is a poor way of reaching a location in the command prompt. You can use commands like "cd" (change directory) and "dir" (display folder contents) navigate the filesystem. The cmd line allows input from the clipboard so if you open the folder in windows explorer, you can get the full path from there and copy it into your cmd window as a parameter for "cd". Search the internet for a DOS tutorial, it can help with understanding cmd.

Comment: If you have programs that you commonly use in the cmd window that are stored in a random folder, you'll normally have to put in the full path to that folder or change directoy before you can run it. To fix this, add the full path to the "path" environmental variable. Then all you need the the exe name and windows will look in that folder automatically and you can then run it from anywhere.

Comment: @Dolt, I just don't want to eveytime typing all the bunch of cd to get to the directory that I want to work to.

Comment: You can type in "cd C:\folder1\folder2\folder3" to go directly there once you enter a cmd session. You can also copy the path from explorer to a cmd window. I would recomend that you follow the advise given by @Mark and hold down the shift button and right click on the folder. That will give you the option to open a cmd window at that location. My suggestions are for when you enter the cmd window and want to move around.

Comment: yes, you are right, but I don't have the need to move around with cmd, I just need to go directly to my working directory ;) cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can't usually just copy executables and expect them to run. There are often other files - dlls, configuration files and, in this case, message files that they need to run. These are usually specified by a relative pathname so the executable can no longer find them and so fails.

To solve this particular error you'd need to locate the message file and copy that, but then there might be something else missing which would prevent the application working.

**UPDATE**

From your comment it's apparent that the path has been modified. That has, in all probability, removed the folder containing the message file from the path, thus rendering it invisible to the application.

I'm not 100% sure whether this is pure Windows Vista or Cygwin (based on the path you quote in your question) and as I'm not that familiar with either (I stuck with XP and I'm moving straight to Windows 7) I don't know what the correct path should be. On XP it's in "C:\WINDOWS\system32", but they might have moved it for Vista.

Do you have a restore point from before you installed these programs yesterday? If so go back to that and reinstall, but don't modify the path.

Restore points are often created by programs just before they install, or you can create them manually. Go to **All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > System Restore** and run the Wizard. The second page should have a list of restore points. Select one from just before you installed these programs. However, you if you know where "cmd.exe" should reside then you could just update the PATH.

Comment: but in some ways, it worked before, only yesterday, I tried to install some programs that asked me for modifying the path, and now it becomes like this. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: Ah - now we get to the problem - the path has been modified.

Comment: Usually, libraries are loaded just by the filename - and each directory in `%PATH%` is tried, starting with `.`

Comment: How do you optain the restore point? I don't use any extra program to do that, does Vista have that function? I haven't tried it yet :d

Answer (score 2):

You're getting those messages because you're running the CMD.exe from a folder different than what's defined in the %COMSPEC% environment variable.  WHY that matters, I'm not sure, probably due to dependencies.

If you want to open a command prompt to a specific folder you can right-click and pick "Open Command Window Here" (built into Vista and 7).  It's extra slick because if you do it on a network share Windows will automatically map a drive letter to it for you.

Another option is to make a new CMD shortcut.

Make a new shortcut, enter %COMSPEC% as the Target, and give it a name you'd like.  Once it's created, edit the shortcut and change the "Start in" path to where you'd like the command prompt to open to.

Comment: Bingo, shortcut to cmd.exe, not a copy of it.  +1

Answer (score 1):

A very simple batch file should do the trick.

```
@set path=%path%;c:\utils
@cd \mydir
@cmd.exe
```

This allows you to add to your environment, select your starting folder and any other thing you want to happen in your system.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is that `cmd.exe` can't find its lanuage file.

To solve it, copy `C:\Windows\System32\en-US\cmd.exe.mui` to the `en-US` subfolder of your directory.  (Or some other language code)

However, `Open command window here` is a better solution.