# How to make a Command Prompt shortcut to open a different directory

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

How do I make a Command Prompt shortcut to open a different directory?

Currently, to navigate to the directory I want, I must open Command Prompt and type

```
C:\Users\me>cd ..\..\repos\RepoSet\UnfortunatelyLongNameAndSimilarToOtherRepos
```

I use this repo all the time, so I would like Command Prompt to open to this directory right away.

Note that I don't want to open a file, or execute any command other than `cd`. I just want to open the directory to my repo.

I am using Windows 10 if that makes a difference.

[Problem with command line in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/95417/problem-with-command-line-in-windows/95430#95430) has an answer by @Dave that seems to be what I want, but I don't know where to place the file he mentions.

Comment: Potentially another solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1312668/windows-7-opening-command-prompt-with-shortcut-icon-in-directory-of-icon/1312681#1312681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

1. Create a `.bat` file called `mydir.bat`
2. Place the file here: `C:\Users\me\CmdFiles`
3. The contents of the file should read

```
@cd C:\repos\RepoSet\UnfortunatelyLongNameAndSimilarToOtherRepos
```

4. Edit the Path environment variable by navigating here Start -> Edit the system environment variables -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> click on Path -> Edit -> Add the path `C:\Users\me\CmdFiles` under the list of paths.
5. Now you can type `mydir` into the command line to access your repo quickly and easily!

---

#### Explanation

Batch files (those ending in `.bat`) can be used to store command line instructions. When you type a command into to the CLI, it will look in your PATH to see if the appropriate batch file exists. Then it will run the commands within.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pin the Command Prompt to your TaskBar
2. Right-click the icon > Right-click Command Prompt > Properties > Shortcut tab:
3. To have it start in `C:\LocationIWantToStart\`: 
    **Target:** `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k cd C:\LocationToStartIn\`

Comment: Pin the Command Prompt to your taskbar, right click the icon, right click Command Prompt, and click on Properties - Start in: C:\LocationIWantToStart\

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, but it works. Thank you!